# How to join these two tables without Foreign Key?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, php

I want to generate monthly report and the total in a year based on position(jawatan) that has been applied.

Table 1 : tpermohonan (mohon_id pemohon_id mohon_tarikh mohon_online)

| mohon_id | pemohon_id | mohon_tarikh | mohon_tkhluput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2018-12-23 | 2019-12-23 |

Table 2 : kod_jawatan (jawatan_id jawatan_kod jawatan_nama)

| jawatan_id | jawatan_kod | jawatan_nama |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A0001 | accountant |

My desired output is :

| Bil | Jawatan(Position) | Jan | Feb | March | Apr | May | Jun | July | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: @NASBS, can you please script the two tables?

Comment: @NASBS Akina has been kind enough to edit the information you left in comments into the question and format it nicely for you. When someone comments, they are usually asking you to *clarify your question*. Unlike some other sites, we are focussed on questions and answers here, so you need to [edit] your original post to improve it based on feedback you receive. Comments don't support formatting and quickly become hard to read - meaning your question might be skipped by people who would otherwise help out. Editing your post also brings more visibility - something that adding comments do not do.

Comment: We will need you to clarify which database product you are using (Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL). You should also say which version you are on. Add that information to your question using an [edit]. Meantime, I have closed this as a duplicate of several general answers.